# How to tell X.org to reload input device module? (Working around suspend-to-ram crash on Acer laptop)

Tags: linux, touchpad, xorg

When X.org boots up, Synaptics touchpad works well. But when I remove the module it falls back to `/dev/input/mice` and don't use normal driver even when touchpad is available again.

```
Xorg.0.log:
...
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Synaptics Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD)
(--) Synaptics Touchpad: touchpad found

# { rmmod psmouse && echo mem > /sys/power/state && modprobe psmouse; }

(WW) : No Device specified, looking for one...
(II) : Setting Device option to "/dev/input/mice"
...
```

How to tell X.org to try it's InputDevice again (without restarting X server)?

P.S. `rmmod psmouse` is needed to prevent crashing of Acer Extensa 5220 when resuming from suspend-to-ram.

**Update**: Found answer myself: Doing `xinput set-int-prop "Synaptics Touchpad" "Device Enabled" 8 1` after reloading the kernel module reloads touchpad. Now suspend-to-ram works OK.

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer here, even if you found by yourself. Hopefully this will help other persons with this issue, in the future.

Comment: @Gnoupi I've just discussed this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49922

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`xinput set-int-prop "Synaptics Touchpad" "Device Enabled" 8 1` restores Touchpad extensions.